# Using knitr (from .Rhtml to html): how to embed a link in an R Figure?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, knitr

I am using knit to convert my .Rhtml file to an .html file.
I am calling the output of a chunk called Q1:

```
<!--begin.rcode Q1,echo=FALSE,fig.show="all",fig.align="center",warning=FALSE 
end.rcode-->
```

Here comes the chunk, it is basically a ggplot2 figure in a 2x2 layout.

```
library(ggplot2)
myplot = list()
   for (i in 1:4){
          x = 1:100
          y = sample(100,100)
          data = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
          myplot[[i]] = ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+labs(title="bla")}

do.call(grid.arrange,c(myplot,list(nrow=2,ncol =2)))
```

Now, when looking at the resulting html file, I would like to incorporate the following feature:
I would like to have a link (e.g. to a database) when clicking on the title of each plot.
Is this somehow possible?

Thx

Comment: Note that this isn't really a knitr question- the hyperlink would have to be added in the PDF (or whatever image format you're using), which would have to be supported by ggplot2 (and I haven't found anything saying this functionality exists).

Comment: Have you considered making a 2x2 table in HTML, and putting one figure in each of the cells, rather than using grid.arrange?

Comment: Does this make a difference? I would still have the problem of assigning a link to this figure.., wouldn't I?

Comment: If you did so, you could write the link in raw HTML, instead of it needing to be in the figure. If the problem is that the link relies on information in R, you could use \Sexpr to grab whatever variable you need from R when you're writing the link. (Notably, this wouldn't work if the dimensions of your figure are determined programatically- that is, if it's sometimes 2x3 or sometimes 3x4)

Comment: I see what you mean... I will think about it. Might be a way to start (yet the dimensions of the figure are indeed determined programatically..)

Comment: sounds like a job for a custom hook in knitr; modify the existing hook that takes care of producing the html for the embedded graphic, adding your hyperlink to it.

Comment: I think I will go for the solution of just adding the link in the HTML file. Hopefully if won't look too ugly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't completely answer your question, but it might get you or someone else started on a full answer.

Paul Murrel's [**gridSVG** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridSVG/index.html) (see also [this useful pdf doc](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/gridSVG/gridsvg.pdf)) allows one to add hyperlinks to **grid**-based SVG graphics. (In theory it should thus work with **ggplot2**; in practice I've just got it working with **lattice**). The [current issue of the R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/2012-2_index.html) includes a couple of articles (["What's in a name?"](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell.pdf) and ["Debugging grid graphics."](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell+Ly.pdf) -- Warning: pdfs) that might help you to best design dynamic searches for name of the grob to which you'd like to add a link (as in my second line of code).

```
library(gridSVG)
library(lattice)

xyplot(mpg~wt, data=mtcars, main = "Link to R-project home")
mainGrobName <- grep("main", grid.ls()[[1]], value=TRUE)
grid.hyperlink(mainGrobName, "http://www.r-project.org")
gridToSVG("HyperlinkExample.svg")
```