# Clickable links as labels in heatmap generated with R / knitr

Tags: r, knitr, heatmap, r-markdown

I work in `R` and write reports using `Rmarkdown` and `knitr`. I generate heatmaps of gene expression, with samples as columns and genes as rows. I'd like to be able to turn the gene labels into clickable links in the resulting HTML or PDF report.

The heatmaps are embedded in the HTML `knitr` output as images, and so there doesn't seem to be a way (as far as I know) of mapping the links onto the heatmap labels from within `R` and `knitr`.

Do any of you know a trick to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using knitr (from .Rhtml to html): how to embed a link in an R Figure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993725/using-knitr-from-rhtml-to-html-how-to-embed-a-link-in-an-r-figure)